# Find an upper bound for the sequence by using given information.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let (an) be sequence.Find an upper bound for |$a_{n+1}-a_n$| the sequence by using given information and evaluate $lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1}-a_n|$.

1)$2\geq|a_n|$

2)$|a_1-a_0|=1$

3)$\frac{1}{8}|a_n^2-a_{n-1}^2| \geq|a_{n+1}-a_n|$

Comment: This is very hard to read.  [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: Hint: Put $u_n=|a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2|$. As $a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2=(a_{n+1}-a_n)(a_{n+1}+a_n)$ and $|a_{n+1}+a_n|\leq |a_{n+1}|+|a_n|\leq 4$, you have $u_n\leq \frac{u_{n-1}}{2}$.